# Wrong value when event handlers are attached in a for-loop

Tags: c#, events

I want to create some `Box` objects inside an array. In the begining I initialized these objects in a for-loop, attaching also an event handler which **passes the current index** `i`.

```
int[] boxes = new int[9];
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
{
  var b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(i, e.Marking);
  boxes[i] = b;
}
```

```
private void OnBoxMarkOccupied(int position, Marking marking)
{
  BoxOccupiedEvent?.Invoke(this, new BoxMarkingEventArgs(position, marking));
}
```

I am expecting that when `MarkingOccupiedEvent` of `boxes[0]` is raised then I am going to retrieve a position equals to **0** from `BoxMarkingEventArgs`. All I am getting though is the value of **9**. And this applies to all boxes inside the array, not just the first one.

Out of curiosity I deleted the code in the loop and wrote the initialization code by hand (since it's only 9 boxes),

```
  var b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(0, e.Marking);
  boxes[0] = b;

  b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(1, e.Marking);
  boxes[1] = b;

  b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(2, e.Marking);
  boxes[2] = b;

  b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(3, e.Marking);
  boxes[3] = b;

  b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(4, e.Marking);
  boxes[4] = b;

  b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(5, e.Marking);
  boxes[5] = b;

  b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(6, e.Marking);
  boxes[6] = b;

  b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(7, e.Marking);
  boxes[7] = b;

  b = new Box();
  b.MarkingOccupiedEvent += (s, e) => OnBoxMarkOccupied(8, e.Marking);
  boxes[8] = b;
```

Guess what, that code works!

**What is wrong with the approach using the for-loop**?

Comment: `i` is capture in the event definition in the foor loop. When the delegates are invoked, i = 9 because the for loop has ended. More details here: https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Closures

Comment: Do you mean when the event is fired? @vc74

Comment: Which version of c# are you using?

Comment: I am using .NetCore 2.1 @ChrisDunaway

Comment: Create a variable within the scope of the loop (`var index = i;`) and pass that to the lambda.  As it is, you are capturing the variable `i`, and it's value will be what it is at the end of the loop for every invocation

Comment: @Themelis When you define your delegates, i is captured (the variable, not its value). When a delegate is invoked, after the end of the loop, i = 9 because the loop has already ended.

Comment: Wait a minute guys, aren't integers passed by value and not by reference?

Comment: Yeah that solved my question @DavidBrowne-Microsoft!

Comment: Yes, but variables are "captured" in a closure, they aren't "passed" to it.  When you create a closure around a lambda, a little hidden class is created to manage state.  It's that state that's biting you

Comment: You made it clear to me @Flydog57, thanks

Comment: They are, but C# creates class behind the scenes to keep the context the delegate was defined in so that it is available when the delegate is finally invoked. This context has a **reference** to i which value, in your case, is useless after the for loop has finished. You can use another variable  as suggested by @Flydog57 to avoid this 'issue'.

Comment: @vc74 - Wasn't there a breaking change regarding variable capture in a closure in the latest versions of C#?  I thought that in later versions, the loop variable was treated as if it were defined inside the loop.  UPDATE:  nevermind, that change only applies to `foreach` loops and not `for`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Indeed, in C#5. This is well documented on Eric Lippert's blog: https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/